# What does numpy's percentile function do exactly?

Tags: python, numpy

From my understanding, [numpy's percentile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) compute the qth percentiles of the data.

But how does it do exactly?

---

Say, given `x = np.array([1.3, 1.7, 2.4, 2.8, 3.5, 5.6, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9])` (10 floats inside).

if I do `np.percentile(x, 100)`, it gives back `9.9000000000000004`.

if I do `np.percentile(x, 90)`, it should returns `8.8`, right? But it gives back `8.9100000000000001`.

---

Why there are such diffs? Are these diffs acceptable?

Comment: Watch out for the fence-post error. If x has 11 elements, then the 10th percentiles correspond to the array elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since version 1.9.0, Numpy's percentile function has an `interpolation` parameter which is described [in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html) like this:

> **interpolation** : {‘linear’, ‘lower’, ‘higher’, ‘midpoint’, ‘nearest’}
>   This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to use, when the desired quantile lies between two data points i and j:
>
> - linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.
> - lower: i.
> - higher: j.
> - nearest: i or j whichever is nearest.
> - midpoint: (i + j) / 2.

It defaults to *linear*. If you want to get `8.8` from your example, run:

```
np.percentile(x, 90, interopolation='lower')
```

Comment: But there are 10 numbers in `x`, and if I am asking for 90%, then it should be the 9th number which no matter what interpolation is should be `8.8` exactly, right?

Comment: No, only if there are 11 numbers in x.

Comment: No. If you have 11 elements, they will line up and correspond to 0%, 10%, 20%, ..., 90%, 100%. In your case, the 9th element would be about the 88.889% percentile.

Comment: @JacksonTale No, this assumption is not correct! You also need an Entry for 0%, i.e. if you want to match the array elements with percentiles in 10% steps, you'll have to provide 11 elements.! See also my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, the 90%-percentile does not have to be an item from the input array.

From the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html):

> Given a vector V of length N, the q-th percentile of V is the q-th ranked value in a sorted copy of V. The values and distances of the two nearest neighbors as well as the interpolation parameter will determine the percentile if the normalized ranking does not match q exactly. This function is the same as the median if q=50, the same as the minimum if q=0 and the same as the maximum if q=100.

The issue with float representation (which is responsible for the slight difference in `np.percentile(x, 100)` compared to `9.9`) is [well known](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).